# Google Maps script Error for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer, google-fusion-tables

I coded a Javascript that initializes a Google Map. The code works perfectly fine while using Firefox browser. I already tried Firebug to find bugs. Firebug says the code is fine. However, the exact same code does not work if I want to run the script in the **Internet Explorer**. So I guess it must be an issue with the IE. The script breaks whenever I want to interact with the fusion table by clicking on the **KML layers** or highlighting certain regions by activating a radio button.

Here is my initialize function:

```
function initialize(){

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: 'XXXX'
    },

        styles: [{
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#00FF00',
        fillOpacity: 0.01,
        strokeOpacity: 0.01}
    },{
     // Objects from the array positive should be colored in a diffrent color
     where: 'OBJECTID IN (' +pos +positive[positive.length-1].ID +')',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#00FF00'
      }

    },{
          where:  'OBJECTID IN (' +pos +positive[positive.length-1].ID +')',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillOpacity: 0.5
      } 
    },{

     where: 'OBJECTID IN (' +neg +negative[negative.length-1].ID +')',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: '#FF0000'
      }

    }, {
          where:  'OBJECTID IN (' +neg +negative[negative.length-1].ID +')',
      polygonOptions: {
        fillOpacity: 0.3
      }
}]
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(event) {
        var  msg = event.infoWindowHtml.toString();
        var countryName = msg.substr(parseInt(msg.indexOf('Name')), parseInt(msg.indexOf('geometry')));
        var CC = event.row['CC'].value 

    for (i = 0; i <countries.length-1; i++){
        var CChilf = countries[i].CC;
            if (CChilf == CC ){
            msg = countries[i].Name + "<br> Balance: " + countries[i].balance;
            }
            else msg = countries[i].Name;
        }

        // Change the content of the InfoWindow
        event.infoWindowHtml = msg;

         });

layer.setMap(map);       
}
```

Here is my header:

```
<link href="/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: did you mention a) what the error is, b) what version of internet exploder you are running on your steam locomotive?

Comment: What is the error that you receive in the console?

Comment: I am sorry. It's my first time seeking for advice on a page like stackoverflow.
A) There is no real error message its more a warning message: 
Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys  But I can't understand why it works fine for Firefox but not for IE.
B) The Internet Explorer version is 8. I know pretty low but it is not possible to change the version.

Answer (score 4):

For google maps support in IE need to add  this script

> `<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js"></script>`

in your index file, It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[IE 8 is no longer supported for the Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport)

See [the release notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#internet-explorer-8-support-ends):

> **Internet Explorer 8 support ends**
>
> 31 August 2015
>
> As of August 31st, 2015, Internet Explorer 8 is no longer officially supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API. See the list of [supported browsers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport). For information on Microsoft's browser support policy, see the [IEBlog post of August 7, 2014](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/08/07/stay-up-to-date-with-internet-explorer.aspx).

([note that IE 9 isn't supported anymore either](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#internet-explorer-9-support-ends))

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The main issue besides the IE version was that the compatibility view is not supported for Google Maps in IE.